# Trying to center a rotated text inside a floated div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to rotate text so it is centered on the div.

I am trying a solution that **doesn't make me change anything (position, float and so on) on parent divs, and neither deal with pixels manually on rotated div (margin, top)**. Is there any way (**best practice**) to achieve it?

**I don't mind browser compatibility**, just looking best way to do it without modifying structure or fixing lengths

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/w5K4j/29/

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="unknown"></div>
    <div id="child">
        <h3>Click this overflowing text that I'd like to V/H center when rotated</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
#parent {
    height:300px;
    width:70px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#unknown {
    float:right;
    height:50px;
    width:20px;
    background-color: yellow
}

#child {
    float:right;
    height:100px;
    width:70px;
    clear:right;
    background-color: orange;
    /*text-align: center;*/
}

h3 {
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
    white-space:nowrap;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.rotated {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: I looked at the fiddle, but I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.  Is the text supposed to overflow evenly on the left/right sides when horizontal, and evenly over top/bottom when vertical?  Or something else?

Comment: I jsut care for a resulting centered text, but yes, I guess some text out of the screen is needed in initial context in order to get a proper rotation.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are saying :(

Comment: Forget about initial state (does not matter if overflows), my goal i updatign the code so that once I click on the link, it gets totally centered and rortated, centered both vertically and horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5K4j/32/

You want `inline-block` on the `h3` to make its box cover its length:

```
h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And keep `text-align: center` on the parent.

**EDIT:** furthermore, you need to make the text centered by giving it a negative left offset by half its width:

```
$('h3').css('margin-left', -$('h3').width()/2)
```

Comment: And don't forget to introduce the nice step you did : $('h3').css('margin-left', -$('h3').width()/2)

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your question, but i think you just want to align your heading `h3` to be centrally aligned.

One way of doing this is using css property `line-height`

```
#child {
    float:right;
    height:100px;
    width:70px;
    clear:right;
    background-color: orange;
    line-height: 50px;
    /*text-align: center;*/
}
```

you can change it as per your requirement.
FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/w5K4j/31/

Comment: Appreciated, but I'm looking for the text being completly centered when clicking on it and rotated. I'm afraid I am not good exposing the situation :'(